# How can I directly scroll to a table row by looking up the row's content in a new window using either js functions or may be angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have an anchor such that when user clicks it, a new page is opened.

Lets say that new page is something like this - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

It has a long table which has the usual tr td elements inside. The table only has a class and no id. I have no control on this page whatsoever as it is maintained by someone else.

Now I want to open this new page in a way that depending on what table content I want to see, the window just scrolls directly on top of that table row. I only know the table row contents. As I mentioned, there are no ids except the table id itself.

I am using angularjs $window to open up this new window.

How can I possibly change the url itself such that it scrolls directly to a table row, without me knowing the row number? I only know the row content.

OR if that's not possible, what else can I do using angular may be?

Comment: You cannot run javascript on a site you do not control like you are describing.

Comment: Is it possible to change the url itself by appending a # ?

Comment: There aren't any IDs on the stack overflow link in the example to be able to jump to by adding a hash tag. If the elements you wanted to skip to had an id (like `<div id="whatever"></div>` it would be possible to use `http://link.com#whatever` to automatically jump to that spot. You're just out of luck if the sections you want to skip to don't have IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot.

If the page opens in a new tab/window, and the rows have no ids, it's impossible. 
You could use an `iframe` to display it on your site and find the element in the `iframe`, though.

Either with jQuery or by `document.querySelector` (where `document` is the `iframe`'s document)

You could even be so sneaky as to hide everything on your site and pretend like the user is on the new site. Maybe even opening **your** site in a new tab/window.